# use script to search for variables in code, then run javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, function

I have a piece of JavaScript that I want on a custom-built intranet to run only for a specific set of users.
The JavaScript is currently on the site and working fine, but to restrict it to the users I think I will need some sort of If>Then>Else statement.
The only problem is, the it'd need to check the current page's source for about 30 variables (one for each staff member I want the display of the JavaScript restricted to).

How can I achieve this?

An example of what I want it to search the page's source (after load) for is: `profilepopup.aspx?uid=63`, OR, `profilepopup.aspx?uid=216`, OR `profilepopup.aspx?uid=185` and so on.
The uid=*xx* is a unique ID for each user, but on some of the site's pages, multiple uid's may appear, so it needs to include the "profilepopup.aspx?" part as well.  That exact string will only appear once.

If any of them exist, I need it to add/use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.zendesk.com/external/zenbox/v2.6/zenbox.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
  @import url(//assets.zendesk.com/external/zenbox/v2.6/zenbox.css);
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof (Zenbox) !== "undefined") {
        Zenbox.init({
            dropboxID: "xxxxxxxx",
            url: "https://foobar.zendesk.com",
            tabTooltip: "Support",
            tabImageURL: "https://assets.zendesk.com/external/zenbox/images/tab_support.png",
            tabColor: "#d8732d",
            tabPosition: "Left"
        });
    }
</script>
```

If any of those variables don't exist, I don't want it to add/use that script.

I'm terrible with funcitons in scripts. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?

**EDIT:**

In fact, I just found another unique ID that is specific to anyone in a particular firm, I only want to limit it to one firm, so this may be better to use in the function because there is only one thing to search for.  The caveat is that the particular string is inside a script in the header... I don't know if this will make it easier or harder.

The firm id is found in `var myFirmID = '487136f1-4e60-4d1c-a98a-4c01e5b14ed6';`.

Comment: Maybe it'd be easier if the function got the myFirmID from the database (MS SQL) and displayed the script I want only if it is equal to 487136f1-4e60-4d1c-a98a-4c01e5b14ed6...?

Answer (score 0):

first try to get the "parameter" value:

```
function getParameter(check) {
    var check = $('#ctl00_MyProfile_lnkMyProfile').data('open'),
        //url = window.location.search.substring(1),
        val = check.split('?');

    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++)  {
        var name = val[i].split('=');

        if (name[0] == check)  {
            return name[1];
        }
    }
}​

// profilepopup.aspx?uid=185
getParameter('uid'); // 185
```

then compare the returned value with your variables

```
var checks = [ "30", "43", "43" ],
    check = getParameter('uid');

if($.inArray(check, check) > -1){
    //do something    
}
```

Hope this helps :/

Comment: I may have mislead you a little.  The `profilepopup.aspx?uid=216` isn't part of the page's URL... it's actually in the source code.  Eg. `<td style="padding-bottom: 6px;"><a id="ctl00_MyProfile_lnkMyProfile" OnClick="window.radopen('profilepopup.aspx?uid=216','wndProfile')" style="cursor: pointer;">Update your profile</a></td>`

Comment: I chose that specific element to look for as it will always be present no matter where that user (in this case 216) will be on the site.  But it will only ever appear once on any particular page.

Comment: first add a data attribute with the file to open only, that way you can check that instead of the "onclick" : `<td style="padding-bottom: 6px;"><a data-open="profilepopup.aspx?uid=216" id="ctl00_MyProfile_lnkMyProfile" OnClick="window.radopen('profilepopup.aspx?uid=216','wndProfile')" style="cursor: pointer;">Update your profile</a></td>` after review my updated code.

Comment: Ok, I've taken your suggestion and have the code (as per example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MX2g6/)) just before the </body> but it has no effect on the page.  In fact, it's removed the zendesk button that was created by the script I mentioned in the question.  I've also added an edit to my question in case using that might make it easier (or quicker for the page load).

Comment: I don't think I can get it to work using your suggested method.
I can't add `data-open="profilepopup.aspx?uid=216"` because that table cell doesn't exist until after the page has queried the database and generated all the content.  (ie. I can't find it in the code).